# I'm trying to export all open matters in Clio and my get requests aren't returning anything

Tags: python, clio-api

I'm trying to use Python to export all open matters in Clio using their api.  My Python skills are not as sharp as I'd like but I think the syntax looks good.  The response I'm getting is always empty, however.

```
mattersUrl = mattersEndpoint + urllib.parse.urlencode({ 'status': 'open', 'fields': 'display_number' })
mattersResponse = requests.get(mattersUrl, headers=oauth2TokenHeader)
```

The mattersResponse.content is empty.  This is basically how Clio API support outlined just at a loss as to why it's not returning any data.

EDIT: Now I see that the matter exports actually showed up in the matters pane of the UI but never returned anything to Python